# Python3.6: Use import os, iter and next to print directory of files with the same extension

Tags: python-3.x, iterator, iteration

Python 3.6

```
import os
files = os.open('dir *.py')
file_iter = iter(files)
print(next(file_iter))
#Output: Volume in drive C is c
```

However when I use a for loop:

```
for file in files:
    print((file), end='')
```

it seems to work fine.

would anyone be able to help here please?

Comment: I would use [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob) over calling some command that could return irrelevant data.

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I'll look into glob.glob. The dir *.py in command line returns the data I'm looking for, I'm just wondering why the iter and next functions aren't working.